# How to do calculation in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two different table values, one has 15 minute intervals and one has hourly values.
I want to create a new table with a column PHF
where PHF= hourly value/4*(the max 15 minute interval for that hour)
How to I write a query for this?

**TABLE1-15 min intervals**

```
ID    PHASE       STARTIME               COUNT
1201; 1;     "2015-01-05 12:15:00-06";    234
1201; 1;     "2015-01-05 12:30:00-06";     344
1201; 1;     "2015-01-05 12:45:00-06";     755
1202; 2;     "2015-01-05 01:00:00-06";     234
1202; 2;     "2015-01-05 01:15:00-06";     244
1202; 2;     "2015-01-05 01:30:00-06";     245
1202; 2;     "2015-01-05 01:45:00-06";     246
```

**TABLE2-the above table hourly intervals**

```
ID   PHASE   STARTIME                      COUNT
1201; 1;     "2015-01-05 12:00:00";        1333
1202; 2;     "2015-01-05 01:00:00";        969
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID   PHASE   STARTIME                      COUNT     PHF
1201; 1;     "2015-01-05 12:00:00";        1333;     0.44
1202; 2;     "2015-01-05 01:00:00";        969;       0.9847
```

PHF is defined as: hourly value/(4*max(15 min value)

so from above example, phf1= 1333/(4*755)=.44

and phf2= (969/(4*246)=.9847

Comment: May be you could show us the table structure, some sample data, the desired output, and the query that you have tried? Consider using sqlfiddle.com for that.

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ab9c/11)**

```
SELECT a.id,
  a.phase,
  b.starttime,
  b.count/cast((4 * a.count) as numeric) AS "PHF"
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.id
JOIN (SELECT id, phase, max(starttime) as "starttime" 
      FROM TableA GROUP BY id, phase) c on a.id = c.id and a.starttime = c.starttime
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful.But I am getting an error though when both the vehicle count is zero it kind of doesn't know how to deal with it.

Comment: You'll have to determine what to do with divide by zero errors